# Calculate field fails when storing "in memory"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

My simple script is the following :

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = "in_memory"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

x= r"C:\naturalEarth\50m_cultural\ne_50m_ports.shp"

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(x, "in_memory","newports")

arcpy.AddField_management("newports", "group", "TEXT")
myfields=arcpy.ListFields("newports")
for x in myfields:
    print x.name

arcpy.CalculateField_management("newports", "group", "myport", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

While it is working when the workspace is set to a geodatabase, it fails when the workspace is set as "in_memory".

Comment: For the in_table parameter for CalculateField try `r"in_memory\newports"`?

Comment: How is "myport" an expression? Or did you just want every row to have that text in that field?